# SaveFileDialog Initial Directory Doesnt work C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, savefiledialog

I cant seem to get it to work for when i click the save file button it opens my given directory

It compiles no error messages just opens as if no initial directory is selected

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
    sfd.FileName = "";
    sfd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\RAKitchens System\\Customers\\" + PassNameLbl.Text;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = sfd.FileName;
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(path));
        bw.Write(textBox1.Text);
        bw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, probably missing something simple

Comment: whats in `PassNameLbl.Text` ??

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give us *any* information about what's wrong. Does it compile? If not, what's the error? Does it throw an exception? If so, what? If you don't get any errors, what does it do compared with what you want it to do?

Comment: does `sfd.InitialDirectory` gets absolute path to the directory(for example `'D:/myfolder/thisIsMyInitialDir'`) ?

Comment: which directory showing in this case > ` if no initial directory is selected` ??

Comment: i think your passig initial directory using this `PassNameLbl.Text` right ??

Comment: Thats the extension to the directory, (customer name) but ive tried it without and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting initial directory for **sfd** instance of `SaveFileDialog` which you are creating locally:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\";
```

But you are opening **saveFileDialog1** instance which is form's field:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Of course, it uses default initial directory. You should either change settings of `saveFileDialog1` or use `sfd.ShowDialog()`

Comment: just changed it to sfd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\"; and it still opens up my documents ? :/

Comment: @BenAllington see update with your problem explanation